# Cleaning up yesterday's files via script

Tags: cron, scripts

I would like to run a cronjob that ran every morning to move the files that were created on the previous day in a specific directory to be moved to a folder that has been created with the previous dates title.

For example, Motion creates a series of jpg files in a directory called snapshots.  I would like to have the script run and find all the files that were created yesterday in the snapshots directory (including avi files it has created), and move them into a folder with yesterday's date as the title on it.

Has anyone tried this before?  Does motion already have this functionality built in and I am just not seeing it?

The next step will be to have it auto purge itself after 7-14 days, but that's a whole other post.

Comment: "Has anyone tried this before?" tried?! it is rather custom to do this. Have a look for rsync examples ;) Have a look at http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Answer (score 5):

This is very simply done through `find`. The relevant options are:

```
   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
          of file modification times.
   -atime n
          File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When  find  figures  out
          how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, any
          fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
          have been accessed at least two days ago.
   -exec command ;
          Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
          arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
          an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
          is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
          it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
          where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both  of  these
          constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to
          protect them from expansion by the shell.
```

So, to move all `jpg` files created in the `snapshots` directory in the last 24 hours, you would run

```
find /home/yourusername/snapshots/ -name '*jpg' -mtime +0 -exec mv {} /path/to/dest
```

The `{}` is replaced by each file name found. QUotes are not necessary since `find` deals with strange file names gracefully before executing the command. The `+0` means "the file was last modified *at least* 1*24h ago as explained in the `atime` section quoted above.

If you want to move these to a directory whose name is yesterday's date, you'd have to create it (using the `-p` option so `mkdir` does not complain if the directory exists):

```
mkdir -p $(date -d yesterday +%F)
```

The `date` command will print yesterday's date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. For example, 2014-06-18. You can combine the two commands into the same `find -exec` call (the `\` after `-mtime` is only there for readability, it allows you to break a command into multiple lines):

```
find /home/yourusername/snapshots/ -name '*jpg' -mtime +0 \
 -exec bash -c "mkdir -p $(date -d yesterday +%F) && mv {} $(date -d yesterday +%F)" \;
```

So, to run this with `cron`, you could add a line like this to your `crontab` (run `crontab -e`):

```
0 9 * * * find /home/yourusername/snapshots/ -name '*jpg' -mtime +0 -exec bash -c "mkdir -p $(date -d yesterday +%F) && mv {} $(date -d yesterday +%F)" \;
```

The above would run the `find` command every day at 9 AM.

Comment: && mv '{}' sounds a little nicer when the files contain escape characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
find /path/to/my/folder/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -l "{}" \;
```

If you want to move them, you may change the exec command:

```
find /path/to/my/folder/ -type f -mtime -1 -exec mv "{}" /path/to/my/newfolder/ \;
```

`"{}"` is the full path to each file name that matched the search.

The `\;` is required at the end of the command line.

You can delete them using `-delete`:

```
find /path/to/my/folder/ -type f -mtime -1 -delete
```

Comment: Wouldn't move essentially "delete" the files? Or is this to do something else?

Comment: It would move the files from one folder to the other. I just added the `-delete` example in case nosaj wanted some information about an auto-purge function. :)